# How to create the grid columns on the fly in dojo?

Tags: java, dojo, web-deployment

I am pretty new to dojo framework, now I have to build a grid using dojo and as I have searched over the net, I didn't find any information on build the grid where I can create the columns depending on the response I get from the server. So please need information on how to build grid with the column names taken from the json response.

for example, if the rest response is:

```
{"id":1,"name":"fuser","lastname":"luser"},{"id":2,"name":"fuser2","lastname":"luser2"}
```

So the grid columns should be id, name, lastname created on the fly without hardcoding the columns names in the javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the JSON from the server creating two new variables for the layout and data store.  After building the JSON for a layout and data store variable, perform eval on it so you can plug it into your grid.

Layout (column headers):

name = Name at the top of the column
field = Internal column ID for processing later if needed
width = Set an initial width

After building your layout var, execute eval() on it so you can use it in your grid.

```
var build_layout = "    var layout = [[{'name': 'ID', 'field': 'id', 'width': '17px'},";
for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
  build_layout += "\n{'name': '" + cols[i] + "', 'field': 'col" + (i+1) + "', 'width': '" + widths[i] + "px'},"; 
}
build_layout += "]];";
eval(build_layout);
```

In your case, build_layout should look like:

```
 [[{'name': 'id', 'field': 'col1', 'width': '17px'},{'name': 'name', 'field': 'col2', 'width': '17px'},{'name': 'lastname', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '17px'}]]
```

Data for the grid:

```
var build_data = "    var data_list = [";
var no_data = true;
build_data += "{ ";
var patt = new RegExp('"',"g");
for (var i = 0; i < JSON_data.length; i++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < JSON_data[i].length; x++) {
    var val = JSON_data[i][x]['val'];
    var chk_val = val.replace(patt,'\\"');
    //alert('val ' + chk_val);
 build_data += "col" + (x + 1) + ": " + "\"" + chk_val + "\"";
    if ( x < (JSON_data[i].length - 1) ) {
      build_data += ", ";
    }
 no_data = false; 
  }
  if ( i < (JSON_data.length - 1) ) {
    build_data += "},\n{ ";
  }
}
build_data += '}];';
if (no_data) {
  build_data = "    var data_list;";
}
//alert(build_data);
eval(build_data);

var rows = JSON_data.length;
var autoH = false;
if (data_list.length < 20 ) { autoH = true; }
if (! no_data) {
  for(var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++){
    data.items.push(lang.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
  }
var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
```

In your case for data in each column (data_list var):

```
   [{col1: "1",col2: "fuser",col3: "luser"},{col1: "2",col2: "fuser2",col3: "luser2"}]
```

Then when you create your grid, plugin layout and store:

```
var grid = new DataGrid({
      id: 'grid',
      store: store,
      structure: layout,
      rowSelector: '20px',
      style: 'font-size:9pt',
      rowsPerPage: 1000,
      columnReordering: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      autoHeight: autoH});
```

You can set the proper width for each column based on the data appearing in the column.
Add this div to your HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Run all your data through the function below...Tweek it as needed:

```
function calcWidthByData(columns) {
  var col_cntr = 0;
  var data_cntr = 1;
  var not_done = true;
  var widths = new Array();
  var fnt_sz = '9pt';
  var tst_item = window.document.getElementById("test");
  tst_item.style.fontSize = fnt_sz;
  var widthPX = 45; //default px width
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
 tst_item.innerHTML = columns[i];
 widthPX = (tst_item.clientWidth + 1);
 //alert(columns[i] + ' ' + fnt_sz + ' width: ' + widthPX + ' original: ' + tst_item.innerHTML);
    widths[i] = widthPX;   
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < JSON_data.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < JSON_data[i].length; x++) {
   var val = JSON_data[i][x]['val'];
      if (val) {
        if (x < JSON_data[i].length - 1) {
          if (tst_item) {
      tst_item.innerHTML = val;
      tst_item.style.fontSize = fnt_sz;
      widthPX = (tst_item.clientWidth + 1);
       }
       var cur_width = widths[x];
       if (cur_width) {
         if (cur_width < widthPX) {
           widths[x] = widthPX;
         }
          } else {
      widths[x] = widthPX;
       }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
  //  var tmp = "widths[" + i + "] = " + widths[i];
 //alert((i + 1) + ' ' + tmp);
  //}
  return(widths);
}
```

The function above basically looks at all the data in the grid and finds the width for each column so it looks visually pleasing.

Comment: What is cols here? I mean if it is the response json from the server, then cols[i] will be a json with the all the field values. So how can this create the column names from the fields of the json object?

Comment: Loop through your JSON string from the server placing field names where 'name' is in the layout var.  Create the values for each column in a separate variable (store in my example).

Comment: Sorry if the above is a lot, I just don't have the time to break it down or edit my code to make it easy.  To make things easier, loop through your JSON data from the server and create layout and store variables on the fly using eval.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

Firstly, your response would be an array of objects.

Require these two files.

```
'dojox/lang/functional/object',
'dojo/_base/array'
```

Then

```
var response = [{name:"jim", lastName:"black"},{name:"another", lastName:"user"}];
var myColumns = [];
array.forEach(object.keys(response[0]), function(key) {
                var field = {};
                field.field = key;
                field.label = key;
                myColumns.push(field);
            });
yourGrid.set('store', new Memory({data:[]})); //Might need this because setting columns on a grid does a refresh and the data might be a different column set now
yourGrid.set('columns', myColumns); 
yourGrid.set('store', new Memory({data:response}));
```